# PyTorch Sparse : NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::is_coalesced' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

When trying to take the autograd derivative for a sparse matrix operation in pytorch, I get the error

```
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::is_coalesced' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'aten::is_coalesced' is only available for these backends: [SparseCPU, SparseCUDA, BackendSelect, Python, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradLazy, AutogradXPU, AutogradMLC, AutogradHPU, AutogradNestedTensor, AutogradPrivateUse1, AutogradPrivateUse2, AutogradPrivateUse3, Tracer, UNKNOWN_TENSOR_TYPE_ID, Autocast, Batched, VmapMode].
```

It says, that it needs the backends
`'aten::is_coalesced' is only available for these backends: [SparseCPU, SparseCUDA,...]`

Usually, when changing the backend in `PyTorch`, one would use `.cuda()` on a model.

How do I change into the `SparseCPU` or `SparseCUDA` backend or is this just a very unprecise error messsage?

Comment: I'm having the issue cpu aswell - both on sparse and dense tensros